# I cant get my if statement to work properly

Tags: c

I have just started coding and whenever i use my if statement by applying conditions i get this error .The error that arise is that irrespective of what i enter it alaways shows yes. Thanks for giving your precious time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
char flag;
printf("Hello World!\n");
printf("Do you want to continue Y or N \n");
flag = getche();
if (flag == 'Y'||'y')
{
   printf("\nYou have entered Yes");
}
else
{
   printf("\nYou have entered No");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need two separate tests: `if (flag == 'Y' || flag == 'y')`. Or you can `#include <ctype.h>` and use `if(toupper(flag) == 'Y')`

Comment: Or `switch(flag) { case 'y': case 'Y': ...`

Comment: `if (flag == 'Y'||'y')` is like `if((flag == 'Y') || 'y')` and because `'y'`is true (because it is not 0)  it is like doing `if (1)`. Take care of the priority of the operators. In the same way don't write `1 < x < 3` because that does not do what you suppose

Comment: `getche()` is non-standard function.